# Select all values of a specific column associated with the max value of another column

Tags: sql

I want to pull data from my table.

```
  line          Entryid
  hello           1
  world           1
  this            1
  is              1
  hello           2
  again           2
  world           2
```

I want to select all the information associated with Entryid 2. Note i cannot say WHERE Project id = 2. I need something like where MAX(Entryid). So the information pulled will be hello  again   world

Comment: So just do what you said, `select * from <table> where entryid = (select max(entryid) from <table>)`

Comment: Thabks very much. Sorted it. I just didn't do a separate select statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do what you want using `join` or a subquery:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.entryid = (select max(t2.entryid) from t t2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a sub query.
         Select * From yourTable Where Entryid = (Select  max (Entryid) From yourTable)